# Can I display an image on an SSRS report ,from a link in database, where the link is URL to an Azure Blob

Tags: azure, reporting-services, azure-blob-storage

I am fairly new to SSRS, and completely new to Azure Blob storage.

Via power app, users upload images associated to a particular work order ID, work site and date.   Images are stored in Azure blob; the URL and file name that points to that image, along with other relevant info, is stored in a table in SQL.

Ideally we would like to allow external users to run a report, with parameters on job site and dates, and get information about the job site, see images associated with that specific job site, etc.

The container on Azure is set to public access to the photos.

My image displays correctly on the report within report builder when I'm using a column that contains the URL to the image.

However, the image itself does not display as a thumbnail when I run the report on our web site.  The column is blank.

I've reviewed:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-an-external-image-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15

When I add an action of 'go to URL', and have the file link set to open the URL in another tab, this action works - the picture opens correctly in another tab.
="javascript:void(window.open(""&fields!FileLink.Value&"','_blank'))"

I've tried setting the image source to external, and typing in a static URL as an expression - again, the photo displays in report viewer, but not on our reporting web site.

I found an article about the unattended execution account, and tried that route, but received an error that our version of SQL server doesn't support windows logins.

I feel like I must be missing something simple - has anyone achieved a similar workflow, or have any suggestions?

Comment: When you view your reporting web site, open developer tools of your browser and see what is the full path used for the IMG src property, and check if it is correctly pointing to the image stored in your blob container.

Comment: You are correct - when I looked in Dev Tools, the URL is showing me something that doesn't remotely resemble the dynamic URL that is built into the report.     
 
url(&quot;data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPcAAAAAAIAAAACAAICAAAAAgIAAgACAgMDAwMDcwNTQyEAgAGAgAIAgAKAgAMAgAOAgAABAACBAAEBAAGBAAIB..etc. 

I'll have to see if I can figure out where this URL is coming from.   Thank you for your assistance.   When I enter a static URL for a picture not on blob, it works, so I'm assuming this has something to do with Azure Blob.

Comment: check the `Content Type` property of the image file stored in Azure Blob storage. It should be one of the image mime types, for example jpeg, gif, bmp etc, but if it is `application/octet-stream` it may not render. your above comment indicates that the base64 encoded image byte stream is trying to be shown in the browser, instead of the url of the image file in blob storage.